# putStrLn etc. not showing because of using map with a function which uses IO Monads?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function which returns ten random numbers. The length of each random number corresponds to the nth Fibonacci number.

This is my code:

```
rndFib = do
   let fibNumbers = map fib [0..9]
   let bla = map printOneRndInt fibNumbers
   putStrLn "All done"

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

printOneRndInt n = do
   gen <- newStdGen
   let randomInts = randomRs ('0','9') gen
       (firstn, _) = splitAt n randomInts    
   putStrLn firstn
```

When I call `rndFib`, all I get is `All done` and none of the `putStrLn`lines are shown. I looks like they are returned into bla, but I just want them to be written out.

Any ideas are very welcome :)

Comment: Haskell is white-space sensitive, but your code does not look properly indented. The three lines under `rndFib` and the four lines under `printOneRndInt` should be indented. This could be contributing to your problem.

Comment: @crockeea thx, they are properly indented, I messed up when pasting it in Stackoverflow. So this is sadly not the problem. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

You've defined an IO action under the name `bla` - but you never use it subsequently. So all your action `rndFib` actually does is print "all done".

To fix it, just put `bla` on a line of its own in the `do` block. And since this is a bit redundant, I would simply drop the `let bla =` from your version. This will also work as intended.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Makes totally sense. Sadly I get the following error now:

`Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [()]
        Actual type: IO ()`

Comment: `map printOneRndInt fibNumbers` has type `[IO ()]`, so you'll need to `sequence` it to pull out the IO.

Comment: @crockeea thx, worked. I need to check out what sequence does.

Comment: Thanks @crockeea, you got there before I could :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Do you mind giving me a simple explenation what sequence does? Or do you have a link where it is explained? I'm still a bit confused. ^^

Comment: @StephanPillhofer while it actually has a more general type, in this context it takes a list of IO actions and makes a single action which runs each action in the list in turn. (And has a result consisting of a list of the individual results. Since your results here are all the "boring" `()`, that isn't relevant here.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thx. Helped a lot :)

Comment: Just to correct my comment above, it's not true that `sequence . map` is the same as `mapM`. I expressed the relationship incorrectly. What I meant was that, for any `f` of type `a -> IO b`, `sequence . (map f)`  is the same as `mapM f`. (The two statements look similar but actually mean different things.)